# How to use Perl CGI::XMLPost correctly?

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm using the perl module [CGI::XMLPost](http://search.cpan.org/~jstowe/CGI-XMLPost-1.5/XMLPost.pm) exactly as described by the documentation and getting the following error:

> Can't call method "data" without a package or object reference at /home/app/public_html/Post.pl line 45.

The code looks like this:

```
use strict;
use CGI::XMLPost;

my $xmlpost = CGI::XMLPost->new();
if(defined $xmlpost) {
    my $xml = $xmlpost->data(); # crashes here
    # ... do something with $xml
}
```

I have tried turning off `use strict;` to see if the upstream system was doing something other than `POST` on the wire. It made no difference.

For reference, a previous version of the code packaged a slightly customised version of CGI::XMLPost 1.5. This was tailored to use `read` instead of `sysread`, which apparently doesn't work (no explanation provided).

Since I am following the documentation exactly, am I missing something? Can anyone point to why `sysread` might break the above simple code snippet? Is there a more reliable way to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that you are calling the `data()` method on an value that isn't a package name or an object reference. Which seems weird as [the constructor](https://metacpan.org/source/JSTOWE/CGI-XMLPost-1.5/XMLPost.pm#L112) should only return either a valid object or "undef".

I think you need to find out exactly what you're getting back from the constructor. Try printing out `$xmlpost` and `ref $xmlpost` to see what you have.

But it's worth pointing out that the latest version of that module is from 2006. It's possible that it no longer works with more recent systems.